# template literals to display the variable name - React.js

Tags: reactjs, template-literals, variable-names

In code below I need to display in `<h1>` a text depending on what props will be passed.
If `props == "a"` text should be from `text_a`, if `props == "b"` text from `text_b`;

```
const Header = (props) => {

const text_a = "Lorem ipsum dolor";
const text_b = "Lorem"

return (
<h1>{here should be a text from const}</h1>
);
}
```

I know that i can use ternary operator but I wondering if it possible to use template literals in this case something like that:

```
<h1>{`text_${props}`}</h1>
```

but in this case it dispaly literally "text_a" or "text_b" but not not what is assigned to the variable.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want to render depending on the values passed to props, something like:

```
const TEXT = {
  text_a: "Lorem ipsum dolor",
  text_b: "Lorem",
};

const Header = (props) => {
  return <h1>{TEXT[props.text] || "Default Text"}</h1>;
};

// "Lorem ipsum dolor"
<Header text="text_a" />;
```

Comment: I was thinking about a slightly different solution but yours seems much simpler and cleaner. Thanks a  lot